# How to decrypt a string in python using RNCryptor

Tags: python, string, encryption, rncryptor

I'm trying to send an encrypted string from one device to another. The first one (with Swift) encrypts the string using RNCryptor and sends it (as a string). How do I decrypt this encrypted string in Python using RNCryptor?

I tried to decrypt the encrypted string with the normal decryption method provided by RNCryptor, but it says that the string is "bad data".

```
 cryptor = rncryptor.RNCryptor()
 decrypted_data = cryptor.decrypt(code.data, password)
        # -> ERROR: bad data (code.data is a string)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what `code.data` contains. I would hazard a guess that `code.data` might contain a Base64 encoded representation of the encrypted data, or something of that sort. `cryptor::decrypt(data, password)` expects you to provide a value of the type `bytes` for the _data_ argument, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @SpencerD code.data is the data extracted from a decoded QR code (using qrtools). Code: ```QRCode = QR(filename="/.../file.jpg")
    QRCode.decode()``` The iOS app generates this QR code. EDIT: I think you're right, this could be a Base64 encoded string. I just noticed that the encrypt function from the iOS App returns a Base64 encoded string. Do I need to convert that Base64 encoded string?

Comment: Yes; `decrypt` expects bytes, not str.